# Version Numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, version

I'm just starting to learn python. For this I want to install the latest version on Ubuntu 18.04.
I have accessed the page https://www.python.org/downloads/.

Python 3.8.3 should be the current verison, right? I entered the following commands and expected phyton 3.8 to be installed on my computer.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3.8
```

Unfortunately, this is not the case. At least this request shows me a different version number.

```sh
python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Maybe I'm not reading it right?

What do the individual numbers mean and why can't I see 3.8 anywhere?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252373/versioning-in-python). What do you mean by "individual numbers"? Did you try running `python3.8` specifically?

Answer (score 1):

The python 3.6.9 is the default version of the Ubuntu 18.04. If You want to update to the 3.8, You can follow this step by step instructions: [Configure python 3 in linux ubuntu](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-ubuntu)